# What's the difference between attempts and retries on laravel horizon?

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-8, laravel-horizon

While trying to debug some strange `MaxAttemptsExceededException` errors, I stumbled upon a strange thing on horizon screen.

For the failed job, it shows

```
Attempts
5
Retries
0
```

which means, the job is attempted 5 times but never retried.

Is this a horizon bug? If not how can overcome this issue?

I have

```
'tries' => 1,
'timeout' => 360,
and 
'retry_after' => 420,
```

I'm using laravel 8.30.1 and horizon 5.7.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Attempts
5
Retries
0
```

Retries is a Horizon feature, it's not related to `tries` config or `public $tries = 5;`.

`Attempts: 5` means the job retried 5 times before it was be considered a "failed" job.

If you press the retry button on Horizon dashboard, you will notice that Horizon will create a new job with label `Retry of 1d56c51b` and the `Retries` of the previous job now is 1.
[image]

In the previous job detail, you also see the list of retries jobs.
[image]